# How to save and load InkCanvas gif file at fixed location without FilePicker

Tags: uwp, gif, inkcanvas, filepicker

I want to save and load `InkCanvas` `gif` file without `FilePicker`.

I saw a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/save-and-load-ink) using `FilePicker`, but I want to save the `gif` file automatically when I click the save button.

For example, when I save 1 `InkCanvas` `gif` file,

Then the `gif` file is saved at in a specific folder on my C: drive.

I also want the file name grow automatically, so that I can load specific `InkCanvas` file.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UWP apps run in a sandbox, so that the user can know what the app is doing and which files on her hard drive it accesses.

In case you want to save files to a location on the user's hard drive, you will have to be given access to this location first. There are several options how to achieve this:

1. [**FileSavePicker**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker) - the option you have discovered, but it requires the user to select the destination file each time manually. If you want to access the selected file next time the app is opened, you can [utilize `FutureAccessList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/how-to-track-recently-used-files-and-folders), where you can store the `StorageFile` under a key, which will allow you to retrieve it again next time.
2. [**FolderPicker**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers#pick-a-folder-complete-code-listing) - let the user select the folder where the images should be stored using a dialog, and you will get read/write permission to this folder. You can then easily create new files there as you require. If you want to access this selected location next time the app is opened, you can [utilize `FutureAccessList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/how-to-track-recently-used-files-and-folders), where you can store the `StorageFolder` under a key, which will allow you to retrieve it again next time.
3. [**Pictures library**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker) - your app can declare the `picturesLibrary` capability in the **package.appxmanifest** file and then get access to the user's pictures library for writing like this: `Windows.Storage.StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownLibraryId.Pictures);`
4. [**Broad file system access**](http://broadFileSystemAccess) - this is the "ultimate" solution and requires your app to target the Spring Creators Update of Windows 10 (pending release in April 2018) or later. You must declare the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability in your app's manifest and then you can directly access any filesystem path the user has access to. The only problem with this is that you need to have a good reason to do this (like building a file explorer app, or similar), because this capability is checked during Microsoft Store Certification and it is possible that your app would get rejected if the presence of this capability would seem unnecessary for the type of application you are publishing.

Comment: Do you have any source that tells whether the "Broad file system access" capability requires a separate capability request or the permission is grated during store submission?

Comment: Although not stated directly in the documentation, it has been mentioned on the UWP Community standup and in notes on dedicated blog post - https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/02/23/windows-community-standup-discussing-multi-instancing-console-uwps-broader-file-system-access/#rfvxFs7iWMrujs37.97

Comment: "If you submit an app to the Store that declares this capability, you will need to supply additional descriptions of why your app needs this powerful feature, and how it intends to use it."

Comment: Yes, I saw that standup. I submitted a request for the capability few days ago. My request is still in progress but MS guy told me that I need a Company account for requesting a restricted capability and I need to move all my apps into a separate company account. That's too much to ask for grating the permission.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, the capability should be allowed for all developers :-O

Comment: Now I can confirm that only company accounts can request for this capability. It's funny how they say "we just need to do a little check that it makes sense for your app" in the standup, then they say something else when you request for it.

Comment: This is a temporary problem - by policy you **do NOT** need to have a corp account for this capability. We'll try to get this fixed on our side Sorry.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply @MartinZikmund ! but actually I can't find that how to use future access list properly. If i want to save **inkstroke** without  **FileSavePicker** , then should i use all you said steps (FileSavePicker ~ Broad file system access)?
I'm Sorry, but can you please give me more information in detail?
Do I use this [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions) ?

Comment: @Kay No, the options are "full solutions", each is self contained, you don't have to combine them. If you want to avoid the picker altogether, solutions 3 and 4 are suitable. If you are OK with user choosing a folder and then saving all the images in this folder, you can use solution 2 as well

Comment: Either broadFileSystemAccess, userDataSystem and even runFullTrust don't allow .NET Standard libraries to access files. This is total nonesense, this makes UWP almost unusable for a broad range of apps and libraries and totally breaks compatibility with old code.

Comment: @Aberro it is however the same as file access to arbitrary paths on Android. Although it may be annoying, it is also good for the users, as app don't clutter the hard drive. `broadFilesystemAccess` allows additional scenarios, but still through the brokered `Windows.Storage` APIs.

Comment: @MartinZikmund which is not defined in .NET Standard nor .NET Core.

Comment: That is the same case as with Android again. It is possible to abstract it away via interfaces though. Alternatively, multitargeting can be used to make things easier

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine two different scenarios that could nudge you into this question:

1. The application needs to store the file for some reason, but the user doesn't need to know about it.
2. You want the user to know and to be able to access the file.

In the first scenario, I suppose you don't care which path you use, so you can use the folder where the application data are stored:

```
var selectedFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

In the second case, you can let the user chose a path then, every time he click the "Save" button you can automatically save the image:

```
private async void btnSelectFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var picker = new FolderPicker();
     picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
     picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

     selectedFolder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

     TxbFolder.Text = selectedFolder.Path;
}
```

In the click event handler of the Save button, you change only where you retrieve the file, the rest remains as in the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/save-and-load-ink):

```
private async void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     // Get all strokes on the InkCanvas.
     IReadOnlyList<InkStroke> currentStrokes = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();

     // Strokes present on ink canvas.
     if (currentStrokes.Count > 0)
     {
         var file = await selectedFolder.CreateFileAsync("InkSample.gif", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

         if (file != null)
         {
             // The rest remains the same as in the example
             // ...
         }
      }
}
```

In the following there is the XAML code and the main page constructor modified:

```
private StorageFolder selectedFolder;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // Set supported inking device types.
    inkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes =
        Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse |
        Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Pen;

    // Listen for button click to initiate save.
    btnSave.Click += btnSave_Click;
    // Listen for button click to clear ink canvas.
    btnClear.Click += btnClear_Click;

    btnSelectFolder.Click += btnSelectFolder_Click;

    selectedFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    TxbFolder.Text = selectedFolder.Path;
}
```

XAML

```
<Grid 
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<StackPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="Header" 
               Text="Basic ink store sample" 
               Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" 
                Margin="10,0,0,0" />
     <TextBox x:Name="TxbFolder" 
              Text="Select a folder" 
              Width="250"
              Margin="24,12,10,12"/>
     <Button x:Name="btnSelectFolder"
            Content="..."
            Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
     <Button x:Name="btnSave" 
            Content="Save" 
            Margin="24,0,10,0"/>
     <Button x:Name="btnClear" 
            Content="Clear" 
            Margin="24,0,10,0"/>
</StackPanel>
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" />
</Grid>
```